# Rails: Force an order on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Building a hiring app with many phases for each open position. User creates a position and then creates phases within that position. I want to be able to force the phases into an order so applicants can be processed through the phases.

The order will later be editable (via drag-and-drop), but for now I just need them to default to an order.

Here is my phase.rb so far with the set_sort_order at the bottom:

```
class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :set_sort_order

  has_many :applicants

  belongs_to :position

  attr_accessible :name, :sort_order, :position_id

  private
  def set_sort_order
    self.sort_order||=self.position.phases.order(:sort_order).last.sort_order + 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`acts_as_list` gem](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'acts_as_list'

# phase.rb
class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => :position, :column => :sort_order
  default_scope :order => 'sort_order'
  belongs_to :position
  # ...
end
```

The above basically takes care of setting the `sort_order` like your code does. It's however a little more efficient, I believe, as it does more work directly in SQL.

Moreover, it adds a bunch of convenience methods for moving records around in the list ([look in `acts_as_list`'s code for more](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb)), while keeping the `sort_order` values sequential. So the first phase added to a position will have `sort_order = 1`, the second will be 2, and so on. And if you use those methods to move phases around, it'll take care of updating the `sort_order` for all the position's other phases, so it's always 1, 2, ... *n*.

*Edit: Added some explanation and a `default_scope` line*

Comment: Flambino, each phase will eventually be a column in a sorted order...like a kanban board. And each column will have cards like a kanban board. Is this still the best route?

Comment: @RailsNewGuy Yes, I should think that it'll work. If it involves custom sorting of records of any kind, `acts_as_list` makes it a lot easier. The code above (I've just updated it with some explanation), simply takes care of keeping the phases properly sorted, so you don't have to worry about 2 records ending up with the same `sort_order` and stuff like that. It's useful enough, that it started out as a part of Rails itself, in fact.